# Best approach for numerically computing the pseudo-inverse of a covariance matrix

Tags: numerical-linear-algebra, pseudoinverse

What are the reasons to prefer eigenvalue decomposition over singular value decomposition for numerically computing the pseudo-inverse of a symmetric real matrix? In the case when you want to form the pseudo-inverse a covariance matrix and you also have access to the original data matrix, does using SVD make more sense?

Using SciPy as an example, the documentation for `scipy.linalg.pinvh` states

> Compute the (Moore-Penrose) pseudo-inverse of a Hermitian matrix.
>
> Calculate a generalized inverse of a Hermitian or real symmetric matrix
>   using its eigenvalue decomposition and including all eigenvalues with
>   'large' absolute value.

Why do we prefer eigenvalue decomposition in this case?

Suppose instead of computing the pseudo-inverse of an arbitrary matrix, you start instead with an $m \times n$ matrix $X$ and want to compute the pseudo-inverse of its covariance matrix $C = XX^*$. It seems like there are two obvious and closely related approaches.

Since $C$ is real and symmetric, it can be orthogonally diagonalized: $C = Q \Lambda Q^T$, where $Q$ contains eigenvectors, $\Lambda$ contains eigenvalues, and $QQ^T = I$. We can get the pseudo-inverse of $C$ from the pseudo-inverse of $\Lambda$ as $C^+ = Q \Lambda^+ Q^T$.

Alternatively, start from the singular value decomposition of $X$ as $X = U \Sigma V^*$. Then $C = U \Sigma \Sigma^* U^*$, and we can get the pseudo-inverse again from the pseudo-inverse of $\Sigma \Sigma^*$.

I thought that computing singular values was always a well-conditioned problem, and that this would mean SVD would be a better approach for computing the pseudo-inverse of a covariance matrix. Is that correct? What other concerns might I be overlooking?

Comment: Generally speaking the SVD is faster and more numerically stable. However, $X X^*$ is $m \times m$ while $X$ is $m \times n$. This means that if $m \ll n$ then it is probably easier to do what you can with $C$ rather than to work with $X$.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, @Ian. In my case I do expect $n$ to be much larger than $m$, so that’s good to keep in mind.

Comment: When a matrix is Hermitian, its singular values are the absolute values of its eigenvalues. Using the SVD and the Schur decomposition are effectively equivalent.

Comment: @MichaelGrant, from a theoretical perspective I completely agree. From a practical computational perspective, is this still true?

Comment: Yes. The symmetric singular value problem is very well behaved. You're gaining nothing by computing the SVD instead, except the extra complexity of having to manage left- and right- singular vectors.

Comment: In fact, LAPACK (for instance) doesn't even supply an SVD for symmetric matrices. You're expected to use the eigenvalue routines instead.

Comment: @MichaelGrant thanks for the pointer. Do you know of a good reference that discusses the eigenvalue problem for symmetric matrices; would you want to write a short answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wouldn't say we "prefer" the eigenvalues to the singular values in the symmetric/Hermitian case. *They are effectively the same thing!* Or, more accurately, the singular values are nothing more than the absolute values of the eigenvalues.

To see why, let $X$ be any Hermitian matrix. Its Schur (eigenvalue) decomposition is $X=Q\Lambda Q^H$ where $\Lambda$ is diagonal, and $Q^HQ=QQ^H=I$. Its singular value decomposition, on the other hand, is $X=U\Sigma V^H$, where $\Sigma$ is diagonal *and nonnegative*, and $U^HU=UU^H=I$ and $V^HV=VV^H=I$.

Alternatively, we can write these decompositions in dyadic form:
$$X=\sum_{i=1}^n \lambda_i q_i q_i^H = \sum_{i=1}^n \sigma_i u_i v_i^H$$
where $q_i$, $u_i$, and $v_i$ are the $i$th columns of $Q$, $U$, and $V$, respectively, and $\lambda_i$ and $\sigma_i$ are the $i$th diagonal elements of $\Lambda$ and $\Sigma$, respectively.

In this latter form, it is simple to see that, given the Schur decomposition,
$$\sigma_i = |\lambda_i|, \quad u_i = q_i, \quad v_i = \begin{cases} v_i & \lambda_i \geq 0 \\ -v_i & \lambda_i < 0 \end{cases}
 \qquad i=1,2,\dots, n$$
gives us a valid singular value decomposition. Our choice to apply the sign flipping to $v_i$ is arbitrary.

Be assured that in practice, this is precisely what you should be doing to compute the singular value decomposition of a Hermitian matrix. The symmetric eigenvalue problem is well-conditioned, and there is no numerical advantage to applying the a nonsymmetric SVD to a Hermitian matrix. In fact, the computation of the singular values of a non-Hermitian matrix $A$ are sometimes computed by applying a symmetric eigenvalue algorithm to the Hermitian matrix
$$\begin{bmatrix} 0 & A \\ A^T & 0 \end{bmatrix}$$
I'll leave it as an exercise for you to prove that this works :-)

EDIT: DGrady's comment alerted me to the fact that I didn't read the second half of the question correctly. In it, he was comparing the merits of computing the SVD of $X$ versus the eigenvalue decomposition of $C=XX^H$. In *this* case, it is indeed going to be a bit better to compute the SVD of $X$ directly.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer! Note that I was comparing the SVD of $X$ (an arbitrary rectangular matrix) to the eigenvalue decomposition of $C=XX^*$ (a Hermitian matrix) — so the singular values of $X$ should be the positive square roots of the eigenvalues of $C$, I think. The goal is to find the pseudo-inverse of $C$, and I was curious if there might be an advantage to approaching this through the SVD of $X$. I appreciate you pointing out that this is not the case, since the eigenvalue problem for Hermitian matrices is well-conditioned.

Comment: Yes, if you are starting with $X$, then using the singular value decomposition may indeed be better. Squaring up to get $C$ will reduce accuracy, but the subsequent eigenvalue decomposition will be stable.